# Asymptotics for $\int_{0}^{T} \zeta(\sigma+ it) \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Denote by $\zeta$ the Riemann zeta function.

It is known that

$$\int_{0}^{T} \zeta(1/2 + it) \mathrm{d}t = T + O(T^{1/2}).$$

But is a similar result for $\int_{0}^{T} \zeta(\sigma + it) \mathrm{d}t$, where $0<\sigma<1$ also known ?

Comment: Should the integrand be the absolute value of zeta rather than zeta itself?

Comment: @Yemon Choi, the integrand is indeed zeta itself.

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

We have, for any $0<\sigma<1$,
$$\int_0^T\zeta(\sigma+it)\,dt = T+O_\sigma(T^{1-\sigma}).$$
To see this, it suffices to show that
$$\int_T^{2T}\zeta(\sigma+it)\,dt = T+O_\sigma(T^{1-\sigma}).$$
By Theorem 4.11 in Titchmarsh: The theory of the Riemann zeta-function, we have
$$\zeta(\sigma+it)=\sum_{n\leq T}n^{-\sigma-it} + O_\sigma(T^{-\sigma}),\qquad T\leq t\leq 2T,$$
therefore by explicit integration
$$\int_T^{2T}\zeta(\sigma+it)\,dt = T + \sum_{2\leq n\leq T}O(n^{-\sigma})
+O_\sigma(T^{1-\sigma}) = T+O_\sigma(T^{1-\sigma}).$$
We are done.

Answer (score 1):

For $1/2<\sigma<1$, the same result should be known, and indeed should follow from the same proof: $\zeta(s)$ can be approximated by a suitably chosen truncation of its Dirichlet series (despite that series not converging inside the critical strip), and integrating term by term yields $T$ from the $1^{-s}$ term and $o(T)$ from all the $n^{-s}$ terms with $n\ge2$. (I don't know whether this method yields the strong error term cited, but the idea is worth sharing anyway: the asymptotic comes from the constant term in the Diriclet series.)

For $0<\sigma<1/2$, the answer will probably be different: for example, on the Lindelöf hypothesis, $|\zeta(\sigma+it)| \asymp t^{1/2-\sigma}$. So the integral will presumably have size around $T^{3/2-\sigma}$. I'm sure this is known (but not by me at this moment...).

Comment: If we have some aproximation $\zeta(\sigma + it) = \sum_n V(n) n^{-s}$ for smooth weight function $V$, the non-constant terms contribute $\sum_n V(n)  i (n^{iT} - 1)  /( n^\sigma \log n)$. If I remember correctly,  $V$ should have height about one and width about $T$, which would make the nonconstant terms contribute at most $O ( T^{1 - \sigma})$. The main term is still $T$. I don't think Lindelöf is relevant.

Answer (score -2):

What you say is incorrect. It is known that 
$$
\int_{0}^{T} \zeta(\tfrac 12 + it) dt = o(T).
$$
Can you please correct the question, and ask again?

Comment: Im so curious now. Can you give a  reference for this claim?

Comment: Well, i hadn't put a refernce because i assumed the result is fairly famous. Indeed, what i wrote in my question is known, see Montgomery-Vaughan, p. 458

Comment: @wqeqwe, it is not true that $\int_{0}^{T} \zeta(1/2 + it) \mathrm{d}t =o(T)$. See Montgomery-Vaughan's ''Multiplicative Number Theory: The Classical Theory'', p.458.

Comment: wqeqwe: Lemma 14.10 in the book @sigma refers to is not consistent with your claim. (The main step in the proof establishes that $\int_1^T \zeta(1/2+it)\,dt = \int_1^T \zeta(2+it)\,dt + O(T^{1/2})$ and we can estimate the second integral easily using the Dirichlet series)