# Inquiry on the bound for $\int_{0}^{T} \Big|\log|\zeta(1/2 + it)| \Big| \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $\zeta$ be the zeta function of Riemann. Is the bound for

$$I_{T}=\int_{0}^{T} \Big|\log|\zeta(1/2 + it)| \Big| \mathrm{d}t$$
known ?

It seems to me that $I_{T} \ll T\log T$ since $\log|\zeta(1/2+it)|\ll \log t$ if $t$ is not an ordinate of a zero. But certainly this is too naive. Is there a better bound ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $I_{T} \ll T\log T$ for $T\geq 2$. For this it suffices to verify that
$$ \int_{T}^{T+1} \Big|\log|\zeta(1/2 + it)|\Big|\ dt\ll\log T,\qquad T\geq 2.\tag{$\ast$}$$
We can deduce this local bound from Theorem 9.6 (B) and surrounding material in Titchmarsh: The theory of the Riemann zeta-function. Indeed, this theorem implies (after taking the real part and applying the triangle inequality) that
$$\Big|\log|\zeta(1/2 + it)|\Big|\leq\sum_{|t-\gamma|\leq 1}
\Big|\log|1/2 + it-\rho)|\Big|+O(\log t),\qquad t\geq 2,$$
where $\rho=\beta+i\gamma$ runs through the zeros of $\zeta(s)$. It follows that
$$\Big|\log|\zeta(1/2 + it)|\Big|\leq\sum_{|t-\gamma|\leq 1}
\Big(1-\log|t-\gamma|\Big)+O(\log t),\qquad t\geq 2,$$
since $\log|t-\gamma|$ is nonpositive throughout the sum. The contribution of the term $1$ in the sum is $O(\log t)$ by Theorem 9.2, hence in fact
$$\Big|\log|\zeta(1/2 + it)|\Big|\leq-\sum_{|t-\gamma|\leq 1}
\log|t-\gamma|+O(\log t),\qquad t\geq 2.$$
On the other hand, from the proof of Theorem 9.7 we learn that there is a constant $A>0$ such that
$$\int_T^{T+1}\sum_{|t-\gamma|\leq 1}\log|t-\gamma|\ dt\geq -A\log T,\qquad T\geq 2.$$
Combining the previous two inequalities, the bound $(\ast)$ follows.

Comment: Wow, that's really ingenious of you ! Thanks !

Comment: @GHfroMO, done.

Comment: @ConsiderTheMathOverFlaw: At https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316668 I claimed that $\int_T^{2T}\zeta(\sigma+it)\,dt = T+O_\sigma(T^{1-\sigma})$ implies $\int_0^T\zeta(\sigma+it)\,dt = T+O_\sigma(T^{1-\sigma})$. This is can be seen as follows. Let $T\geq 2$ be fixed, and let $K$ be the largest integer for which $2^K\leq T$. Then, for any integer $1\leq k\leq K$, we have $\int_{T/2^k}^{2T/2^k}\zeta(\sigma+it)\,dt = T/2^k+O_\sigma(T^{1-\sigma}/2^{k(1-\sigma)})$. The sum of these yields $\int_{T_0}^T\zeta(\sigma+it)\,dt = T+O_\sigma(T^{1-\sigma})$, where $T_0:=T/2^K$ lies in $[1,2]$. Done.

Comment: Thanks, but where did $$\int_{T/2^k}^{2T/2^{k}} \zeta(\sigma+ it) \mathrm{d}t = T/2^{k} + O_{\sigma}(T^{1-\sigma}/2^{k(1-\sigma)})$$ come from ?

Comment: @ConsiderTheMathOverFlaw: It came from $\int_T^{2T}\zeta(\sigma+it)\,dt = T+O_\sigma(T^{1-\sigma})$ that I proved under that link. $T$ is arbitrary, so one can replace it by $T/2^k$.